# Authorization error occurred

Tags: paypal

I can succesfully create invoice through REST api, but I get `Authorization error occured`
when using live API endpoint.

In configuration I can see that `Direct credit cards` feature for live transactions is not enabled, since its not available for my country (Slovenia).

Is error occuring because of this reason?

Answer (score 1):

You have to have verified business account.

Got a hint from https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/issues/74

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with invoices.

As you correctly stated, a business account needs to be used.

Following the getting started guide from PayPal, there is an example email under merchant info. You need to change that email to your business address.

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices/ \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
  -d '{
  "merchant_info": {
    "email": "merchant@example.com",
    "first_name": "David",
    "last_name": "Larusso",
    "business_name": "Mitchell & Murray",
    "phone": {
      "country_code": "001",
      "national_number": "4085551234"
    }
...
```

That is the example request. You need to replace `merchant@example.com` with your actual account email.